# Using .split on a string in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, split

For an input like 12,34,56;78,91;50,60;

I want to split the string by semi-colon delimit and then those strings split by comma delimit

ex:

```
puts "Input: "
input = gets.chomp
s_array = input.split(";")
for i in 0..s_array.size
    puts s_array[i].split(",")
end
```

It will successfully print with `puts` but after I get an error

```
undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass <NoMethodError>
```

Whats the reason for this error?

Comment: This is not what you've asked for, but you might find it of interest: `"12,34,56;78,91;50,60;".split(/[,;]/) #=> ["12","34","56","78","91","50","60"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `..` for `...`

```
for i in 0...s_array.size
```

Creating a range with `..` is inclusive, while `...` is not, e.g.

```
1..5  # => 1,2,3,4,5
1...5 # => 1,2,3,4
```

So the variable `i` overflows the array, in your case if the array size is 5, array_s[5] will be nill.

Comment: @user1763861, you should accept this question as correct, then.

Answer (score 2):

A more rubyish approach is:

```
input.split(";").each { |x| puts x.split (",") }
```

You should use [Array#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-each), it is not rubyish to use `for` and there are very few cases where `for` loop is required in place of `each` in ruby and the `for` keyword delegates to `each` even when used.